# Gulp and index.html issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I have 4 html files.

**index.html,**

**menu.html,**

**dishdetail.html,**

**contactus.html,**

And I am using gulp for testing purposes and live preview. However,the index.html is not concatenated inside the dist folder. All the other folders such as images,styles and scripts are concatenated. So this is how I set up the gulp.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
stylish = require('jshint-stylish'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
usemin = require('gulp-usemin'),
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
rename = require('gulp-rename'),
concat = require('gulp-concat'),
notify = require('gulp-notify'),
cache = require('gulp-cache'),
changed = require('gulp-changed'),
rev = require('gulp-rev'),
ngannotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
del = require('del');

 gulp.task('jshint', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/scripts/**/*.js')
.pipe(jshint())
.pipe(jshint.reporter(stylish));
});

 // Clean
   gulp.task('clean', function() {
   return del(['dist']);
 });

 //Default task
 gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function() {
 gulp.start('usemin', 'imagemin','copyfonts');
 });

gulp.task('usemin',['jshint'], function () {
return gulp.src('app/*.html')
  .pipe(usemin({
    css:[minifycss(),rev()],
    js: [ngannotate(),uglify(),rev()]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

// Images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
 return del(['dist/images']), gulp.src('app/images/**/*')
   .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, 
   interlaced:    
   true })))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
  .pipe(notify({ message: 'Images task complete' }));
});

gulp.task('copyfonts', ['clean'], function() {
gulp.src('./bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}*')
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
gulp.src('./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/**/*.{ttf,woff,eof,svg}*')
.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'));
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync'], function() {
// Watch .js files
gulp.watch('{app/scripts/**/*.js,app/styles/**/*.css,app/**/*.html}',    
['usemin']);
  // Watch image files
gulp.watch('app/images/**/*', ['imagemin']);

});

gulp.task('browser-sync', ['default'], function () {
var files = [
  'app/**/*.html',
  'app/styles/**/*.css',
  'app/images/**/*.png',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'dist/**/*'
 ];

 browserSync.init(files, {
  server: {
    baseDir: 'dist',
    index: 'index.html'
  },
 reloadDelay: 1000
});
    // Watch any files in dist/, reload on change
 gulp.watch(['dist/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

And when I type in cmd **gulp**,I get this error.

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: write after end
at writeAfterEnd (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\AngularJs\Week3\03_SPAs\node_m
odules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\readable-  
stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:229:
12)
at Transform.Writable.write (C:\Users\Theodosios\Desktop\AngularJs\Week3\03_
SPAs\node_modules\gulp-minify-css\node_modules\readable-  
stream\lib\_stream_writa
ble.js:272:20)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

All the modules are instralled through npm. They are shown here

**package.json**

```
{
"name": "conFusion",
"private": true,
"devDependencies": {
  "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
  "del": "^2.2.2",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-cache": "^0.4.5",
  "gulp-changed": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
  "gulp-imagemin": "^3.1.1",
  "gulp-jshint": "^2.0.4",
  "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
  "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0",
  "gulp-notify": "^3.0.0",
  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
  "gulp-rev": "^7.1.2",
  "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
  "gulp-usemin": "^0.3.28",
  "jshint": "^2.9.4",
  "jshint-stylish": "^2.2.1"
},
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.10.0"
}
}
```

Thanks,

Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `gulp-useref` plugin

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-useref
```

### Update gulpfile.js as below

```
var useref = require('gulp-useref');

gulp.task('usemin',['jshint'], function () {
  return gulp.src('./app/*.html')
  .pipe(useref()) 
  .pipe(usemin({
    css:[minifycss(),rev()],
    js: [ngannotate(),uglify(),rev()]
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of possible reasons:

First, [`gulp-minify-css`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) is deprecated and they recommend using [`gulp-clean-css`](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css), so you should try updating that.

Secondly, [`gulp-usemin`](https://github.com/zont/gulp-usemin) is designed for node `>=4.0` and your `engines.node` is set to `>=0.10.0`.